# Duplicate method compareTo when running build-service in liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I have an entity, let's say Xyz and want to override the compareTo method. So I put the code in the XyzImpl class. But when I'm run build-service I get this error:

"Duplicate method compareTo... in XyzWrapper".

I saw that [a bug](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-11283) was opened about this but never closed. Any idea how I could get rid of that?

I'm using Liferay 6.2ga on Linux 64 bits with OpenJdk 7.

Comment: add this information to the bug, maybe even fix it and contribute the fixes back? You might need to backport the fix to your version once it's fixed on master (e.g. 7.0). Find somebody to send a pullrequest to or discuss the nature of the issue in forums or on IRC.

Comment: Ok I added a comment to the [bug](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-11283)